# Passing parameters into a url

Tags: javascript, redirect

I need to pass some parameters into a URL

For example, my URL is `mypage/generator/`

So my generator consists of a generator(code, id, text)

Is the following a correct way of doing it

```
Check:function () {
    var generator = code + "," + id + ", " + text;
    Window.location.href = "mypage/" + generator + "/"
}
```

Comment: Turn off "smart quotes" when editing code, you can't use curly quotes.

Comment: URL parameters are usually like `mypage/generator/?name=value&name=value&name=value`

Comment: so your URL will be like this `mypage/code101,20,thisIsMyText` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
function check(){
var generator=code +","+ id +","+ text;
window.location.href="mypage?data="+generator+"";
}
```

and you can access the data from `request.getparameter("data");`

This might help you!